# Wordpress - Set post_date

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set the `post_date` of a blog post to Wordpress via XMLRPC.

I'm sending the data as a string:

```
$pubdate = '2010-04-08 13:46:43';

'post_date'=>$pubdate,
```

It appears `'post_date'` is correct?

I also found this post losely related to the issue: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/330597

Can anyone suggest how I would post the date as: `dateTime.iso8601`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post the date as a `<dateTime.iso8601>` element (assuming you're using the built-in XML-RPC client within WordPress, you want to cast your date as an `IXR_Date` object.

```
// Convert the time to an integer value for parsing.
$pubdate = strtotime( '2010-04-08 13:46:43' ); 

// Convert the date to the right kind of object.
$pubdate = new IXR_Date( $pubdate );
```

Now, when you pass your array of arguments to make the request, passing `'pub_date' => $pubdate` will create the correct XML element.

See [this other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/67518/46) to a similar question for more information if you want a full, working example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
$pubdate = date('c',strtotime('2010-04-08 13:46:43'));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php